# How to store hex value in shellscript

Tags: shell

I am new to shellscript

I have this program

```
for(( s=0x001; s <=0x00f; s++))
do
echo $s
done
```

I want to print s values as `1,2,3,4.....a,b,c,d,e,f`

But when I run above program,I have seen the output as `1,2,3,4,5,6......13,14,15.`

I want to print the hex values only.

How to pass hex values in pipe.Lets say I have to pass this hex in pipe along with some other arguments.How to do that?

Lets says I have to pass some arguments to access device driver in pipe.

```
echo "8 $s q" | /usr/sbin/tejas/test /dev/slot$1/tupp_fpga$devNo | grep "at offset"
```

Here s should contain hex values.How to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `printf "%x" $s` should do. It is part of the POSIX standard, and implemented as a built-in command in `bash`:

```
$ type printf
printf is a shell builtin
```

…so the documentation can be found in `man bash`, at least for the Bash shell.

Comment: You can pipe `printf` just as you would pipe anything else: `printf "%x" 15 | cat`, for example.

Comment: +1, but note that `man bash` (and `help printf`) only describe the bash builtin's _extensions_ to the printf _executable's_ functionality (notably, option `-v` and format specifier `%q`). To see the core functionality, including descriptions of the supported format specifiers (such as `%x` here), use `man printf`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `printf` command. It's standard and works more or less like the C function.

```
printf "%x\n" $s
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure to understand the updated question but...

... if you require the given format, something like that will do the job:

```
print "8 %x q" $s | /usr/sbin/tejas/test /dev/slot$1/tupp_fpga$devNo | grep "at offset"
```

If your not familiar with the *printf*-style functions please refer to one of the many web pages describing the [various format](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) available.

On this particular case, the `%x` in the *format* string will be replaced by the *hexadecimal* representation of the next argument. Given that the `s` variable hold the value 10<sub>10</sub> (or 0xA<sub>16</sub> or 013<sub>8</sub> -- which are indeed the same), the `printf` internal command will write the string `8 a s` to the standard input of your `/usr/sbin/tejas/test` tool.